# Why DataTemplate return class name instead of control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate

I want create custom control add property Info and InfoTemplate for example.
I define ControlTemplate in generic.xaml using ContetnPresenter for Info property.
When I don't use InfoTemplate it's works fine, but when I apply ItemTemplate the content is represents as class name string. This same template applied to GroupBox work like expected. What do I wrong? I need some extra code in OnApplyTemplate?
Bellow is print-screen my app and sources. Red border is a GroupBox, blue is my Control. Green border is part of DataTemplate.

[image: App print-screen]

**EDIT:**
For testing I create class MyGroupBox inherited form GroupBox and override method OnHeaderChanged

```
public class MyGroupBox : GroupBox
{
    protected override void OnHeaderChanged(object oldHeader, object newHeader)
    {
        //base.OnHeaderChanged(oldHeader, newHeader);
    }
}
```

In that situation GroupBox.Heder behave like my MyCustomControl and display text instead of control. So question is: What should I implement in my control event to work like I want?

---

**MyCustomControl.cs**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication7
{

    public class MyCustomControl : ContentControl
    {
        static MyCustomControl()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyCustomControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyCustomControl)));
        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
        }

        public object Info
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(InfoProperty); }
            set { SetValue(InfoProperty, value); }
        }

        public DataTemplate InfoTemplate
        {
            get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(InfoTemplateProperty); }
            set { SetValue(InfoTemplateProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty InfoProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Info), typeof(object), typeof(MyCustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty InfoTemplateProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(InfoTemplate), typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(MyCustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    }
}
```

**Generic.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication7">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyCustomControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyCustomControl}">
                    <StackPanel>

                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">Info</TextBlock>
                        <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Info"/>

                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">Content</TextBlock>
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**MainWindow.xml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication7"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        DATA_CONTEXT
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="dataTemplate">
            <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="5">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>

        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="4">
            <GroupBox HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource dataTemplate}">
                <GroupBox.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                </GroupBox.Header>
            </GroupBox>
        </Border>

        <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="4">
            <local:MyCustomControl InfoTemplate="{StaticResource dataTemplate}">
                <local:MyCustomControl.Info>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                </local:MyCustomControl.Info>

                My content
            </local:MyCustomControl>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;


namespace WpfApplication7
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So scrapping my answer and starting over now that I have a better understanding of what is being requested. The idea here is to basically recreate a custom `GroupBox` like control. The issue is that the `DataContext` for the `Info` property in the custom control (which is basically the `Header` property for `GroupBox`) isn't coming out as the `DataContext` of the custom control itself like it is when a `GroupBox` is used.

So the issue is that the chunk of UI that you set to the `Info` property is never added as a logical child of the control so it doesn't get added in such a way as to inherit the `DataContext` as is happening for the identical code when used in a `GroupBox`. To do this just update your custom control class to the following:

```
public class MyCustomControl : ContentControl
    {
        static MyCustomControl()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyCustomControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyCustomControl)));  
        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
        }

        public object Info
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(InfoProperty); }
            set { SetValue(InfoProperty, value); }
        }

        public DataTemplate InfoTemplate
        {
            get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(InfoTemplateProperty); }
            set { SetValue(InfoTemplateProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty InfoProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Info), typeof(object), typeof(MyCustomControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(MyCustomControl.OnHeaderChanged)));

        private static void OnHeaderChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var obj = (MyCustomControl)d; 
            obj.RemoveLogicalChild(e.OldValue);
            obj.AddLogicalChild(e.NewValue);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty InfoTemplateProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(InfoTemplate), typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(MyCustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    }
```

This will fix the issue, however, it should be stated that it would likely be cleaner just to have derived from `HeaderedContentControl` rather than from `ContentControl` as `HeaderedContentControl` already has all of this set up for you right out of the box and also already has a `Header` and `HeaderTemplate` that you could use in place of your `Info` and `InfoTemplate` properties which would save you some code.

If you want to get this working without bothering with logical children and so forth you can just update the binding in your chunk of UI that you set `Info` to and have it use a `RelativeSource` that searches for the custom control ancestor and then has a path of "DataContext", that will manually override the whole issue although you would have to remember to do that every time.

My bet would be it would be best for you to just derive from `HeaderedContentControl`, it looks like that should have all of the functionality you are looking for already baked in.

Comment: That not fully working. If I do like you write then there is not green border on Info TextBlock. This behaviour is identical when I don't set InfoTemplate. My generic.xaml is analogue to ControlTemplate for GroupBox which was generated in Blend.

Comment: If you want to keep the green border then you should add `ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding InfoTemplate}"` to the ContentPresenter line that I included in my answer. Your ContentSource was setting this before (along with other properties) as explained in the article that I referenced in my answer.

Comment: I know how ContentSource works. Are you try run my code with yours changes? That's not work for me or maybe I do something wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I said that wrong. You should only have that update and scratch the other one. So you should have `<ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding InfoTemplate}"/>` in your generic.xaml. The `Content` binding overrides the `ContentTemplate` which is why you see the `TextBlock.ToString` result again. For me I am seeing "my content" show up with the green border so I am guessing it is what you are looking for. If not let me know. Also the other `ContentPresenter` also shows "my content" because the default template is getting used there.

Comment: No. I want to see "DATA_CONTEXT" with green border because that is defined for `Info` property (`<local:MyCustomControl.Info> <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/></local:MyCustomControl.Info>`)

Comment: I think I get what you are looking for now, but to be sure I put a screenshot of what I think you are looking for as an edit in the answer. Let me know if this image is the desired outcome.

Comment: Yes. That I looking for.

Comment: So you are looking at making your own custom `GroupBox` essentially? The reason your binding is failing is because the `DataContext` for your `TextBlock` is the `TextBlock`. To remedy that quickly just change the `Binding` for `Text` to use a `RelativeSource` that finds the first ancestor of the type of your custom control and then a path of "DataContext". That gave the result that I have an image for. Not sure right off the bat why yours isn't working the same as the `GroupBox`, but why not just derive from `HeaderedContentControl`? That is what it is there for.

Comment: Ok, I redid my answer in light of better understanding your question. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111968/discussion-between-siwydym67-and-chiune-sugihara).